# Physics based circulation models

Tags: atmosphere-modelling, atmospheric-circulation, synoptic

How useful are physics based models when considering circulations at synoptic scales? Are they useful? Can we not make predictions, observe trends based on data alone? I am studying A.E.Gill's model on tropical circulation and this thought often occurs to me due to the approximations made in the model.

Comment: Where would understanding be, if you'd only (linearly) extrapolate from data? Where would be the capability to predict nonlinear events?
In particular Gill's model is useful not only for Earth but also for other planets.